# Why does this API request work in Postman but it raises an error in Django test?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-testing

I post to my API to create an account from Postman

```
{
    "email": "snifter@gmail.com",
    "display_name": "outrageous canteloupe",
    "password": "GramDaddyff!!5"
}
```

It works, and a new account is registered in the databse.

Then I try to make the same request from a Django test.

```
class AccountAPITestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_create_account(self):
        c = Client()
        response = c.post('/accounts/', {
            "email": "snifter@gmail.com",
            "display_name": "outrageous canteloupe",
            "password": "GramDaddyff!!5",
        })
        account = Account.objects.get(display_name='big_ouch')
        self.assertTrue(account)
```

And I get the following error.

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_create_account (accounts.tests.AccountAPITestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mcm66103/Documents/python/photo-contest-BE/accounts/tests.py", line 28, in test_create_account
    "password": "use_in_migrationsDaddyff!!5",
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 526, in post
    response = super().post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, secure=secure, **extra)
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 356, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 421, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 496, in request
    raise exc_value
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 114, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 24, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/Users/mcm66103/Documents/python/photo-contest-BE/accounts/serializers.py", line 19, in create
    return Account.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
  File "/Users/mcm66103/Documents/python/photo-contest-BE/accounts/managers.py", line 17, in create_user
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 495, in __init__
    _setattr(self, prop, kwargs[prop])
  File "/Users/mcm66103/.envs/photo-contest-BE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 546, in __set__
    % self._get_set_deprecation_msg_params(),
TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead.
```

Here is my user models.py.

```
from accounts.managers import AccountManager


class Account(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = AccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Here is my managers.py.

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

I am trying to test Account creation in a repeatable way. I would expect the test to behave the same as Postman. Why do they behave differently, and how do I correct this error?

EDIT:

views.py

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = None
    queryset = Account.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return AccountSerializer
        if self.action == 'create':
            return CreateAccountSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
class CreateAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Account.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

Comment: Your error refers to `groups`, but none of the code you've posted does. Maybe post that DRF viewset and serializer too?

Comment: @AKX, I added the relevant sections of view.py and serializers.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using serializers? Could it be that your test method isn't actually pushing a JSON object? Although your string looks like a JSON object, Python needs to know that it is, indeed, a JSON object. It also looks like there may be some conflicting data within your test method. Your Postman post request is clean.

Why are you using a test method anyway? If you use the Django Rest Framework, it has built-in API testing pages that will mimic Postman.

EDIT:
Try this:

```
class AccountAPITestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_create_account(self):

        data = {
            "email": "snifter@gmail.com",
            "display_name": "outrageous canteloupe",
            "password": "GramDaddyff!!5",            
        }
        serializer = CreateAccountSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid:
        new_user = serializer.validated_data

        c = Client()
        response = c.post('/accounts/', new_user)

        account = Account.objects.get(display_name=data.display_name)
        self.assertTrue(account)
```

Make sure that you import your serializer into that view. Here you're declaring data as a Python object, and then passing it to the serializer that will convert it into a JSON object.

I changed the filter you're using for your account variable to check to see if the new user you're submitting has been created (it seemed to me that's what you're trying to accomplish with your test).

I actually just had a very similar issue last night with something I was working on.

Comment: Hiya Jake,

I included the serializer and view in an edit above. 

Also, Client.post() expects a python dictionary object for the data parameter, but it looks like it actually works when I specified the content_type parameter as "application/json."

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So, I gave it my best shot. Without having your full code sitting on my desktop, i can't test it. Serializers are still a bit finicky to me. What I suggested would have you build your Python object, serialize it and ensure it's valid. Then pass that validated_data to your client.

Comment: I don't think I was very clear, but your answer helped me solve it. Here is what I changed. `c.post(PATH, DATA)` to `c.post(PATH, DATA, content_type='application/json')`.